# only static data member templates are allowed

Tags: c++

I have two classes called Component and Transform. The Transform class is derived from Component class.

component.h:

```
class Component {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T* ptr_;
};
```

transform.h:

```
class Transform : public Component {
public:
    Transform();
};
```

transform.cc:

```
Transform::Transform() {
    ptr_<Transform> = this;
}
```

It gives me error 'error C3376: 'Component::ptr_': only static data member templates are allowed'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot have a data member that is a template. You probably want the whole class to be a template.

Comment: This code seems very strange in general. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're trying to declare a non-static member variable template. That's wrong, as the error message explains.

If `ptr_` is supposed to always point to an object of type `Transform`, then it doesn't need to be a variable template. All you need to do is to declare the `Transform`:

```
struct Transform;

struct Component {
    Transform* ptr_;
};
```

---

If `Component::ptr_` is supposed to always point to its derived instance, then this is a bad design. What's better replacement design depends on why you think that `ptr_` would be useful. Given that inheritance is involved, I'm guessing that the better solution involves a virtual function.